# Show aspx form as modal on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

is there a way where I can show an aspx form without using javascript?

Is there like this code in a asp button?

```
protected void btnLookUpPayment_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        webLookUpPayment wblp = new webLookUpPayment();
        wblp.ShowModalDialog();
    }
```

Because using a javascript popup modal is actually not my option, I have a gridview in my modal and upon clicking a row in that gridview, i will populate another gridview in another form, I can't explain it thoroughly because it is confusing, just want to know if there is a way where I can show a modal without using any javascript?

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: You need to consider that showing a modal happens *on the client side* so some C# running on the server is merely going to be turned into HTML, CSS, and JS at the end of the day. You haven't given a valid reason why you "can't use JavaScript". If you've got a modal popup working, you probably are running JavaScript already. You can download the web page via JavaScript or embed it via an iframe.

Comment: Use the ASP.NET Ajax ModalPopupDialog extender. It's not how I'd prefer to do it but if you absolutely cannot use client-side code, give it a look.

Comment: @mason Actually I am using a javascript on the pop up modal, Keep in mind the my modal is another aspx webform. There is a gridview in there where in if i click it's selected index, the value from the gridview will populate another gridview from my previous form. Did you get it or is it confusing? I can't use javascript because i'm populating my gridview from the database, and i don't know how to load a stored procedure in my javascript.

Comment: @eljon_i3 You're trying to dictate the restrictions on the solution based on false premises. No, JavaScript alone can't access your database. But JavaScript can make [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls into your server side, where you can have an [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) respond with the proper information. This is usually considered a good architecture: it avoids a lot of the overhead of creating a new page and going through the entire lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

It will perfectly work. For pop up new .aspx from code behind

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('About.aspx', 'hello',  'width=700,height=400,scrollbars=yes');</script>");
```

And for new window without pop up

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", "About.aspx"));
```

mark it as answer if it works. Thanks